# Why Symfony 2 uses NativeSessionStorage for testing?

Tags: php, symfony, session, phpunit, native

I'm writing tests for my controllers and I get the following error for a controller using session :

> Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by \"/home/rightink/public_html/project-file-manager/1.0/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php\" at line 139.

The stacktrace shows that Symfony is using "NativeSessionStorage.php" when executing the tests which should not be the case.

I have the following config_test.yml file :

```
imports:
- { resource: config_dev.yml }
- { resource: parameters_test.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        collect: false

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
```

The controller is using the session like this :

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

Note : the stacktrace shows that this is the "start" method that leads to the exception.

Any idea of why I got this session error ?

Thanks,

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `session` element as stand alone usage.

Please use the session as [symfony2 service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#core-symfony-and-third-party-bundle-services) as example:

```
public function indexAction($bar)
{
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set('foo', $bar);

    // ...
}
```

The Native Session is for PHP classic usage, the other options are for Mongo, Memcache and other. More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#custom-save-handlers)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks. In my case, session was used in a service but injecting it in place of creating it works !.

Note that in the doc of Symfony session, they create the session var, they never inject it or get the service : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: Yes @Vincent, You refer to the doc that explain how to use the symfony component without all the framework.